# SocketIO: How to emit event in a single request

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I have an issue about **emiting event in a single request**. I have read many issues in Stackoverflow but I can make my case success. Please check for me.

My `server.js`:

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

const io = require('socket.io').listen(server)
const socketEvents = require('./socketEvents')
server.listen(PORT, err => {
  if (err) {
    console.log('Cannot run SOCKET!')
  } else {
    app.io = io
    socketEvents(io)
  }
})
```

Then, this is my `socketEvents.js`

```
const socketEvents = (io) => {
  io.on('connection', (socket) => {
    const socketId = socket.id
    console.log(`User with ID ${socketId} connected`)
    socket.on('disconnect', () => {
      console.log(`SocketId: ${socket.id} disconnected`)
    })
    socket.on('openRoom', function(payload) {
      var roomID = payload.room_id
      var user = payload.user
      console.log('User', 'with socket', socket.id, 'watching', 'room', roomID);
      socket.join(roomID);
    });
    socket.on('leaveRoom', function(uid) {
      console.log('User', socket.id, 'leave', uid, 'room');
      socket.leave(uid);
    });
    socket.on('send-message', (payload) => {
      console.log('User', socket.id, 'send a message data to room', payload.room_id);
      MessageCtr.add_message(payload)
      .then(response => {
        io.to(payload.room).emit("updateRoom_" + payload.room, response)
      })
    })
  })
}

module.exports = socketEvents
```

I want to emit event: `io.to(payload.room).emit("updateRoom_" + payload.room, response)` when Send request with method POST:

```
router.post('/new', function(req, res) {
  MessageCtr.add_message({...req.body, 'user_id': req.user.user_id})
  .then(response => {
    req.app.io.to(req.body.room_id).emit("updateRoom_" + req.body.room_id, response)
    res.json({ 'success': true, 'data': response.dataValues });
  })
});

module.exports = router;
```

This line `req.app.io.to(req.body.room_id).emit("updateRoom_" + req.body.room_id, response)` is not work. Please give me reason for it. Thank in advance!

My Client (VueJS):

```
this.$socket.on('updateRoom_' + this.room.id, function (payload) {
  console.log(payload);
  vm.$store.commit('chat/SEND_CHAT', payload)
})
```

Comment: what app in the first snippet -     app.io = io?

Comment: @AbhishekMani I updated it. Please check bro!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Utilize Nodejs [event emitters](https://nodejs.org/api/events.html) to solve this problem.

In your Api you can add event emitter([process.emit](https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process)).

```
router.post('/new', function (req, res) {
    MessageCtr.add_message({ ...req.body, 'user_id': req.user.user_id })
        .then(response => {
            // req.app.io.to(req.body.room_id).emit("updateRoom_" + req.body.room_id, response)
            process.emit("send_socket_response", ({ room_id: req.body.room_id, response }));
            res.json({ 'success': true, 'data': response.dataValues });
        })
});
```

and in your socket code file add listener ([process.on](https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process))

```
const socketEvents = (io) => {
    process.on("send_socket_response", (data) => {
        let room_id = data.room_id;
        let response = data.response;
        io.to(room_id).emit("updateRoom_" + room_id, response)
    })
    io.on('connection', (socket) => {
        const socketId = socket.id
        console.log(`User with ID ${socketId} connected`)
        socket.on('disconnect', () => {
            console.log(`SocketId: ${socket.id} disconnected`)
        })
        socket.on('openRoom', function (payload) {
            var roomID = payload.room_id
            var user = payload.user
            console.log('User', 'with socket', socket.id, 'watching', 'room', roomID);
            socket.join(roomID);
        });
        socket.on('leaveRoom', function (uid) {
            console.log('User', socket.id, 'leave', uid, 'room');
            socket.leave(uid);
        });
        socket.on('send-message', (payload) => {
            console.log('User', socket.id, 'send a message data to room', payload.room_id);
            MessageCtr.add_message(payload)
                .then(response => {
                    io.to(payload.room).emit("updateRoom_" + payload.room, response)
                })
        })
    })
}
```

Comment: This is a smart way bro. But I want to ask how can I broadcast using `socket.to(payload.room_id).broadcast.emit('updateRoom_' + payload.room_id, payload)`. I try with `io.to(room_id).broadcast.emit("updateRoom_" + room_id, response)` in your process and it not work

Answer (score 1):

Can you try this,use global variable
`app.io = io` replace with `global.io = io`

```
global.io.to(req.body.room_id).emit("updateRoom_" + req.body.room_id, response);
```

Instead of

```
app.io.to(req.body.room_id).emit("updateRoom_" + req.body.room_id, response)
```

Comment: Cannot read property 'to' of undefined in this line `app.io.to(req.body.room_id).emit("updateRoom_" + req.body.room_id, {'response': 'aasds'})` bro (`const express = require('express');
const app = express();`)!

Comment: please try to console `app.io` and see what is logs? @KitKit

Comment: `app.io` log prints `undefined`

Comment: @KitKit just because of scope

Comment: It's doesn't give error anymore. But client not work. I update code in my client

Comment: okay, also just try to log that now, check if has some reference to that object

Comment: I try logging in console `global.io.to(req.body.room_id)`, How can I check it have event `"updateRoom_" + req.body.room_id` to emit, bro?

Comment: you can get the binded events if you try to log socket object